# comparing memory and data content using awk

Tags: awk, gawk

I have two files containing memory in the first field and data contained in the second

File 1:

```
0x60008798 4567
0x60009912 3457
0x60008814 3111
0x60006590 9116
0x60004942 4443
0x11111111 0000
```

File 2:

```
0x60008798 4567
0x60009912 3457
0x60008814 3666
0x60006590 9666
0x60004942 4443
0x22222222 1111
```

I wish to check if for a given memory value (i.e. the first field), the data (i.e. the second field) in both the files match.

I am trying to find out how to use awk for the same, but the cases explained are too complicated. Can anyone help?

One alternative is that I use grep, or maybe I write a C code, but I thought I could use awk

My requirement: The memory should have the same data in either file... these are memory and data contained in the memory taken at different points and they should match, if not, I throw an error.
I found one solution myself:
 awk 'BEGIN { while (getline < "file1"){arr[$1] = $2}}{if (arr[$1] != $2){print $0}}' file2

Thanks,

Tejas

Comment: Can you please elaborate with more inputs in your sample file and expected output?

Comment: @JaypalSingh: I've invented some input to make testing easier :-)

Answer (score 1):

To find the string `0x60008798` using `GNU awk`:

```
awk '/^0x60008798$/ && FNR==NR { value=$1; data=$2; next } { if ($1 == value) printf ($2==data) ? "MATCH\n" : "NO MATCH\n" }' file1.txt file2.txt
```

This assumes:

- that there are no duplicate memory values in either file.
- that you only care strictly about whether something matches or it doesn't.
- i.e. no output will be generated if two matching values (one from each file) cannot be found.

Answer (score 1):

please edit your post to inlcude your required output. In the meantime, here is an alternate solution using a std unix untilty `comm`. Do `man comm` or `info comm` to find out more.

```
comm -3 <(sort file1) <(sort file2 )
0x11111111 0000
        0x22222222 1111
0x60006590 9116
        0x60006590 9666
0x60008814 3111
        0x60008814 3666
        0x99999999 1234
```

We've sorted both files so their in alpha order

The the `comm -3` filters the 3rd column of output, which are
any matched items that are found.

What remains are differences between the first file and then 2nd file, sorted.

**edit**

OR to see what values are the same, exclude the first 2 columns of `comm` output:

```
comm -12 <(sort file1) <(sort file2 )
0x60004942 4443
0x60008798 4567
0x60009912 3457
```

IHTH

Answer (score 0):

```
file1val=$(awk -v addr=$addr '$1 == addr {print $2}' File1)
file2val=$(awk -v addr=$addr '$1 == addr {print $2}' File2)
if [ "$file1val" = "$file2val" ]
then echo match
else echo no match
fi
```